# Why debug.log doesn't work?

Tags: debug

I used the proper way to setup Wordpress debugging:

1.) Set up the `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
```

2.) `apache` is the owner of `wp-content` folder

3.) `apache` has the proper `SElinux` rights:

```
drwxrwxr-x. 11 apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0  4096 Aug  5 19:32 wp-content
```

I found and followed all the previous Q&As and solutions here in this topic.
But Wordpress still doesn't update `debug.log` in `wp-content` folder.

I'm working on `Fedora28`.

What could be the problem?

**EDIT:**

```
if (!function_exists('write_log')) {
    function write_log ( $log )  {
        if ( true === WP_DEBUG ) {
            if ( is_array( $log ) || is_object( $log ) ) {
                error_log( print_r( $log, true ) );
            } else {
                error_log( $log );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use the function above for get debugging info, like end of some function etc.

Comment: Permissions? Is the file writable? CHMOD 777.

Comment: @WPZA as you can see at 3.) it has 775 and apache is the owner.

Comment: Actually it needs max. 644, I think.

Comment: Well it will not show `debug.log` file unless there is something to show. How are you showing debug logs? Try creating the `debug.log` file manually and then in your theme's `functions.php` file put the code `error_log('Debug log loading');`

Comment: @Fayaz See **EDIT** section of my question.

Comment: @Fayaz I just gave a try as another test and added `error_log('Debug log loading');`, but nothing happened unfortunately.

Comment: I don't see any other problem that can be diagnosed from your given information. Another thing to note is: did you set all the constants before the `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');` line in `wp-config.php` file? Also, there can be two `wp-config.php` files, one on the same directory of wp installation and the other one in one directory up, make sure you are using the correct one.

Comment: @Fayaz Thank you for the tips but I have only one wp-config.php and I defined the constants as I wrote above. I checked it twice e.g. if I set `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` to `true` it shows warning in HTML, if set `false` it doesn't, so as I expected.

Comment: @Geeocode If you have access to Apache, can you not just skip the debug.log stuff and go straight to superior standard PHP debugging practices, such as the actual PHP error log? XDebug even?

Comment: @TomJNowell As a next step I won'T have other choice. The current state is the result of a server migration and on the previous server with the current settings the WP debugging method worked well, so I thought I missed something and I don't like the unsolved puzzles, thus I gave it a try. Furthermore I won't have specific WP error message and warning logging this way.

Comment: @Geeocode `error_log` outputs to the PHP error log, the `debug.log` functionality is just a helper code that tries to change where the PHP error log is written to. `debug.log` when it works **IS** the PHP error log. If you know where PHP normally writes errors and warnings to then you should use that instead. If anything you will get **more** not less information. `error_log` is a PHP language feature, not a WordPress function

Answer (score -1):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325708/debug-logs-at-wordpress-not-working):

> You have `@ini_set('display_errors', 0);` - which will tell PHP (not
>   WordPress) to stop displaying errors. WordPress requires errors to be
>   turned on in order for it to pass them to the appropriate place.
>   `define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);` or `define('WP_DEBUG', false);`
>   should take care of hiding them on the front end for you.

Comment: From the WP Codex:
*WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY is another companion to WP_DEBUG that controls
whether debug messages are shown inside the HTML of pages or not. The
default is 'true' which shows errors and warnings as they are
generated. Setting this to false will hide all errors. This should be
used in conjunction with WP_DEBUG_LOG so that errors can be reviewed
later. Note: for WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY to do anything, WP_DEBUG must be
enabled (true). Remember you can control WP_DEBUG_LOG independently.*

Comment: `@ini_set('display_errors', 0);` line stops showing errors in the front end, but it doesn't stop producing them. So it doesn't affect the `debug.log` file.